# Parallelogram and Congruence

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle, quadrilateral

Let point M be outside the parallelogram ABCD such that $\angle MAB = \angle MCB$. Prove that $\angle AMD = \angle CMB$. [image]

I am trying to prove $\triangle MDE \sim \triangle MBC$ but I am having trouble seeing how to do this.

Comment: You have posted, just today, a bunch of problem without any of your own thoughts. I think it is time to learn how MS works. Please, try hard to solve the question before post here. People are spending their time trying to help ypu but it seems to be useless.

Comment: What Arnaldo means is, work on the problem for a bit before asking on here so that you can provide us with some of the work you have done. This helps us determine if you are on the right track or not. Therefore, we can provide hints and/or solutions.

Comment: i have been staring at this problem for a while now and i dont know where to begin...so any hints or solutions i can work on understanding would be greatly appreciated right now @YunusSyed

Comment: Are you sure that the question is formulated correctly? It seems to me that $\angle AMC \ne \angle CMB$ since $\angle AMC=\angle AMB + \angle CMB$. Is it perhaps that you are asked to prove $\angle AMB=\angle CMB$?

Comment: @Tyron i fixed it...it was supposed to be $\angle AMD$

Comment: @danish Please do not vandalize posted questions, not even yours.

Answer (score 2):

Let $AMKB$ be parallelogram, which gives that $DMKC$ is parallelogram.

Hence, $\measuredangle MAB=\measuredangle MKB$.

Thus, $\measuredangle MCB=\measuredangle MKB$, which says that $MKCB$ is cyclic.

Hence, $\measuredangle CMB=\measuredangle BKC$ and since $\measuredangle AMD=\measuredangle BKC$, we obtain $\measuredangle AMD=\measuredangle CMB$.

Done!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be the circle circumscribed around triangle $BCM$. Produce $AB$ until it intersects the circle $k$ the second time at the point $A^*$ and produce $DC$ until it intersects the circle $k$ the second time at the point $D^*$. As $DC$ is parallel to $AB$ (because $ABCD$ is a parallelogram), the segments $CD^*$ and $BA^*$ are parallel, hence $A^*BCD^*$ is a trapezoid, inscribed in the circle $k$. Therefore $BC = A^*D^*$ as well as  $\angle\, D^*A^*B = \angle \, CBA^*$ and $\angle\, CMB = \frac{1}{2} \text{arc}(CB)= \frac{1}{2}\text{arc}(D^*A^*) =  \angle \, D^*MA^* $.

[image]

However, because $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and $BC \, || \, AD$, we have $A^*D^* = BC = AD$ and $\angle \, CBA^* = \angle \, DAB$. Thus  $$\angle \, D^*A^*B = \angle \, CBA^* = \angle \, DAB$$ Since the polygon $BCD^*A^*M$ is inscribed in $k$, combined with the assumptions of the problem,
$$\angle \, MAB = \angle\, MCB = \angle \, MA^*B = \angle \, MA^*A$$ so triangle $MAA^*$ is isosceles with $A^*M = AM$. Finally, $$\angle \, MA^*D^* = \angle \, MA^*B + \angle \, D^*A^*B = \angle \, MAB + \angle \, DAB = \angle \, MAD$$ which yields that triangles $A^*D^*M$ and $ADM$ are congruent and for that reason $$\angle\, AMD = \angle\, A^*MD^* = \angle \, CMB$$

Comment: Nice proof! +1.